# XML error validating .xml against .xsd file

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, xsd

each time I run my app engine application in the devserver locally the appengine-application.xml file seems to be automatically re-generating. Each time it reverts back to a version with a simple syntax error.

Question: where is the file regenerated/copied from? How do I edit it and cause the changes to persist?

There is an opening < missing at the beginning of this file. I have done the following to attempt to edit and save the file:used terminal commands vi- vim- and nano as an admin and a root user, as well as xcode and a plain text editor.

here is the file with the error, appengine-application.xml ( missing and oppening '<' before '?xml version="1.0 encoding=...').

file path:../guestbook/guestbook-ear/target/guestbook-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/appengine-application.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<appengine-application xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>single-loop-665 </application>
</appengine-application>
```

here is the appengine-application.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"     targetNamespace="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="appengine-application" type="ns:appengine-applicationType" xmlns:ns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0"/>
 <xs:complexType name="appengine-applicationType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="application"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

this is the error:

> [INFO] Caused by: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: XML error validating /Users/jamesjohnson/guestbook/guestbook-ear/target/guestbook-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/appengine-application.xml against /Users/jamesjohnson/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.8/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.8/docs/appengine-application.xsd

Comment: AFAIK, the file shouldn't get regenerated by simply running the devserver. Could you post the exact command you're running that causes it to be regenerated?

Comment: thanks for responding!   mvn appengine:devserver

Comment: I'd really really be surprised if that's what's actually causing the issue. To be sure, you did save the file, close it and reopen to make sure it's saved before running it right? The only command that I'd see overwrite this is mvn archetype:generate. Maybe one test is to delete the file, and run mvn appengine:devserver, to see if it gets recreated, my bet is that it won't.

Comment: yes I am absolutely sure I saved properly and exited the terminal. I also tried the same with the gui editors. I also just did as you suggested and deleted, in terminal with the rm- command, appengine-application.xml. The same file was recreated in the same directory as I described with the exact same code and syntax error ( missing opening < )

Comment: Color me surprised. Let's try something, can you go ahead and run the tutorial back from 'mvn archetype:generate'?

Comment: Alright @Bero Dotnet it works! I'm not really sure why it was broken, I'm positive I went through all of the steps carefully before. I would still like to find out why the apengine-application.xml was regenerating each time with the error.

Comment: hahaha that's cool. I have no idea why though. Somehow maybe the downloaded skeleton got corrupted?

Comment: I'm curious though, now that it's working, if you delete the xml file, then running the dev server regenerate it again?

Comment: yes, I deleted it, exited, then re-ran the app. The file was re-generated, this time however it did not have any syntax errors

Comment: so from that extent, I guess that the original file is downloaded when  getting the skeleton. I recommend you use your OS search function to search for the original file that contains similar strings. Then try to make a change to it, and regenerate the file to see if the changes appear. That would explain it.

Comment: So I've tried reproducing and the thing is that I don't have an appengine-application.xml in my guestbook test (even after running dev) which makes sense as that's only needed for different modules.. Can you let me know which test app you were tying this on?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking ( the java appengine-skeleton? ) anway the problem is occuring again with a different file. web.xml is now not allowing me to make changes and has a syntax error. I'm not sure how theses files are re-created or how cause edits made to them to persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

so it appears as though there is a copy made of the app each time it is run. This means that all the xml files and everything else contained in the guestbook-war/src directory is copied into a file called appname-version-SNAPSHOT. It appears that the SNAPSHOT file is where the source code for the app is compiled and run from.

In order for edits to persist you must edit the files contained  in your

```
appname-war/src/main
```

directory.

The confusing part is that the error thrown will point you to the copy of the code located in the

appname-ear/target/appname-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/appname-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

if you edit the code in these files it will have no significance at run time. These files are generated each time the app is run.